# App name does not exist in Instruments dSYM Locations

Tags: xcode, instruments

I'm trying to re-symbolize my project in instruments since it's not showing functions name under TimeProfiler. But I'm not able to find my App under the dSYM Locations.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, but for some reason the profiling schema under xcode had 'release' config instead of 'debug'!! changing that back to debug solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the problem in my case.

Comment: @BVisschers Did you check your debug config?

Comment: I'm sure I checked it. But can not confirm it anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with spotlight and Lion.
Unfortunately "mdimport ." command does not work in all situations ( this command should tell where to look for the dsym files, if you were in the dsym folder it must work)

So i end up locating manually in instruments the files under: /Users/YOUR_USER_HERE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_APP_HERE/Build/Products and then select the appropriate folder and DSym files.

To be able to select Library folder you need to write this command: chflags nohidden ~/Library/